# how to add webview in table layout in android

Tags: android

Hi
 can anybody tell  how to add webview in table layout give example

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <TableRow>
      <WebView android:id="@+id/webview01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I want to array of webview in table row dynamically

Comment: you mean you want a list of webview? my guess is you'll have to write your custom adapter for that.

Comment: You'll have a problem with this solution, since tableRow always wraps the height to the content, and the webview before it's loadedhas a height of zero, so the tableRow won't show